# How to check if file is executable using bitwise operations in Rust?

Tags: rust, file-permissions, bitwise-operators

In many programming languages one can find if file is executable or not,  by doing a [bitwise and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) between the [mode bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions) and `0111`, something like:

```
is_exec = (mode & 0111) != 0
```

Where `mode` represents the mode bits with an octal value something like `100755`, or `755`.

Command line example:

```
perl -e 'printf "%o\n", (stat "file")[2] & 0111'
```

I am trying to follow this approach using Rust, but can't make it work, this is the code I am using:

```
fn print_dir(path: &PathBuf) {                                                                                                                                            
    let files = match fs::read_dir(&path) {                                                                                                                               
        Err(f) => {                                                                                                                                                       
            println!("{}", f);                                                                                                                                            
            return;                                                                                                                                                       
        }                                                                                                                                                                 
        Ok(f) => f                                                                                                                                                        
    };                                                                                                                                                                    

    for f in files {                                                                                                                                                      
        let file = f.unwrap();                                                                                                                                            
        let mode = file.metadata().unwrap().permissions().mode();                                                                                                         
        println!("path: {} {:o} - {} {:0}", file.path().display(), mode, mode, mode & 0111);                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

The `mode & 0111` is not behaving like expected as it always returns positives. I tried similar code in Go, and it was very straight forward:

```
var is_exec bool
if m := f.Mode(); !m.IsDir() && m&0111 != 0 {
    is_exec = true
}
```

Any idea of how to do this with Rust?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rust, a leading `0` does not mean a number is in octal. You want to use the prefix `0o` instead:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", 0111);  // 111
    println!("{}", 0o111); //  73
}
```

[Other prefixes](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#numbers) you may be interested in:

```
0xBEEF // Hex    (Base 16) => 48879
0o1234 // Octal  (Base  8) =>   668
0b0101 // Binary (Base  2) =>     5
```

Answer (score 4):

You're close, you'll want to use this (I use `unwrap()` in the example for brevity):

```
let mode = fs::metadata(&f).unwrap().mode();
if mode & 0o111 != 0 {
    println!("binary...");
}
```

Credit due to [some code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/77987ba89894997c174ac8b01185c0dc12913fa5/src/tools/tidy/src/bins.rs#L39) I was working with a while ago.